# WireMock does not transform response

Tags: wiremock

I'm having an issue using WireMock, I've extended `ResponseTransformer` and implemented all required methods, it looks like this:

```
public class TempResponseTransformer extends ResponseTransformer {

    @Override
    public Response transform(Request request, Response response, FileSource fileSource,
                              Parameters parameters) {
        return Response.Builder.like(response).but().status(404).body("1").build();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean applyGlobally() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "temp-response-transformer";
    }
}
```

Now I want to apply this particular transformer to one of the stubs, that I wrote, stub looks like this:

```
private static void initTempStub() {
    stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/api/v1/temp"))
            .withHeader("AccessToken", matching("[a-zA-Z0-9]+"))
            .withHeader("CliendID", matching("[a-zA-Z0-9]+"))
            .withHeader("ClientSecret", matching("[a-zA-Z0-9]+"))
            .willReturn(aResponse()
                    .withTransformers("temp-response-transformer")));
}
```

When I start service and perform post calls I do see that transformer is applied, however responses actually not being transformed.
I've tried to apply transformer in config section when starting service as well, but it doesn't help.

So my question is how should I apply `ReponseTransformer` correctly so it would transform my responses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, think I've figured it out.
Here is an issue(?) with WireMock that I was able to figure out while looking at the internals, here is how I passed config:

```
new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig()
.extensions(TempResponseTransformer.class)
.options().notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true)))
```

And an issue with this code is when you call `options()` from `wireMockConfig` it would create new instance of `WireMockConfig`, so I had to extract this config into separate piece of code like this:

```
    var wireMockConfig = new WireMockConfiguration();
    wireMockConfig
            .extensions(SamplesResponseTransformer.class)
            .notifier(new ConsoleNotifier(true));
```

Comment: If you think this is an issue, please log it at the WireMock Github page.